# Rcpp quantile implementation

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a Rcpp double containing a NumericVector x. I would like to get the .95 quantile of such x within the Rcpp code flow. I do not know how can I get it. Is there an RcppArmadillo implementation?

Comment: Do you know the distribution of `x`? There are some built in sugar functions that will calculate it per distribution, such `qnorm` etc.

Comment: x is empirical I need the th-percentile

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/c-libraries-for-statistical-computing)? Dirk demonstrates that the Boost Math library contains a quantile function. @DavidArenburg's answer seems to work fine for an integral response, but if you want an estimation of continuous data, you'll need something more robust such as Boost's `quantile()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a `Rcpp` expert and my function probably needs lots of improvement, but it seems that you can easily create your own Rcpp quantile function (which will be not so accurate on small vectors due to high chance to skewness and problems with indexing on non-integer indexes, but improves as the vector grows)

```
library(Rcpp) # You can use sourceCpp() instead of cppFunction if you wish
cppFunction('NumericVector Cquantile(NumericVector x, NumericVector q) {
  NumericVector y = clone(x);
  std::sort(y.begin(), y.end());
  return y[x.size()*(q - 0.000000001)];
}')
```

Testing on `1e+3` vector

```
set.seed(123)
y <- rnorm(1000)
qs <- seq(0, 100, 25)/100

quantile(y, qs)
#           0%          25%          50%          75%         100% 
# -2.809774679 -0.628324243  0.009209639  0.664601867  3.241039935 


setNames(Cquantile(y, qs), paste0(qs * 100, "%"))
#          0%         25%         50%         75%        100% 
# -2.80977468 -0.62957874  0.00729009  0.66441586  3.24103993
```

Looks close enough. So the 95% quantile for our vector `y` would be

```
Cquantile(y, .95)
## [1] 1.675697
```

---

There are also some Sugar quantile functions for knows distributions such normal, gamma, etc. that can be used instead, see [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-sugar.pdf) for some examples.